# Trying to use Firebase Dynamic Links, doesn't open app on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm currently working on application and we'd like to use Firebase Dynamic Links for deep linking our content. I'm using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) to generate the links. It generates successfully and they work just fine on Android, in that it leads to the Play Store page for the app and prompt the user to install the app if they don't have it installed already. Otherwise it opens the app with the deep link content. On iOS however regardless of if the user has the app installed or not the Dynamic Link redirects to our App Store page. We have our team ID in our Firebase settings, the bundleid and the appstoreid are both in the request body. Is there anything I'm missing?

I would appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a answer to your specific issue, and I have the same problem with my own app.  I did however find [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug) useful, in order to rule out possible causes...

For Objective C, add,

```
[FIRDynamicLinks performDiagnosticsWithCompletion:nil];
```

For Swift, add,

```
DynamicLinks.performDiagnostics(completion: nil)
```

And note any diagnostics in the console.

Mine is reporting success, but still the link does not work reliably.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issue and I'm also looking for a solution on the web. 
What I did find, is that you need to have the apple app site association file correctly configured and updated in the Firebase console. The change propagation takes from a few hours to 2 days. 
Check it under this link (just change the <> brackets to what you actually have)

`https://<Your-App-Specific-Link-Name>.page.link/apple-app-site-association`

Also in my case, part of the problem was with `TEAM_ID`. I'm working on a project that was abandoned by the original team and my `TEAM_ID` is different from theirs, but Firebase (and Apple for that matter) requires the `TEAM_ID` of the original team that actually created the app for the first time (I call it original_team_id) to be set, not the newer one. Again, this might not be your case, was mine and I managed to get the links working in Firefox Focus/Chrome but not in Safari... Still looking for the missing dots and pieces to make it finally working like advertised.

EDIT:
I did run the diagnostics tool mentioned by @Snips in the answer above, and for me the console shows that my App id is different from the Team id, this is what I was talking about in the original answer:

````
performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.```
Still, "no errors" but doesn't work in Safari.
````